# Edit specific line in a textbox

Tags: vba, ms-word

I wrote this macro to generate a textbox with more than one line:

```
Sub multipleLineTextBox()

    Dim Box As Shape
    Set Box = ActiveDocument.Shapes.AddTextbox( _
        Orientation:=msoTextOrientationHorizontal, _
        Left:=50, Top:=50, Width:=200, Height:=200)

        Box.Line.Style = msoLineThinThin
        Box.Line.Weight = 6
        Box.TextFrame.TextRange.Text = "first line" & vbCrLf & "second line"
        Box.TextFrame.TextRange.Font.Size = 20

End Sub
```

The last line edits all the text in the textbox to be size 20.

How can I edit each line separately?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Use this:

```
Sub multipleLineTextBox()
    Dim Box As Shape
    Set Box = ActiveDocument.Shapes.AddTextbox( _
        Orientation:=msoTextOrientationHorizontal, _
        Left:=50, Top:=50, Width:=200, Height:=200)
        With Box
            .Line.Style = msoLineThinThin
            .Line.Weight = 6
            .TextFrame.TextRange.Text = "first line" & vbCrLf & "second line"
            .TextFrame.TextRange.Paragraphs(2).Range.Font.Size = 20
        End with
End Sub
```

Comment: This is in the low quality posts queue.  To avoid deletion,  you may want to explain your answer.

Comment: @RohitGupta for this particular case the expanation is not required.

Answer (score 1):

TextRange has a Paragraphs collection. You can loop that or work with each item individually. For example

```
Dim bxRange As Word.Range
Set bxRange = Bix.TextFrame.TextRange
bxRange.Paragraphs(1).Range.Font.Size = 12
bxRange.Paragraphs(2).Range.Font.Size = 10
```